# Cannot bind array to CDbCriteria (Yii)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I want to use WHERE IN(array) clause in my query.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addCondition('id_cty_cmp IN(:ids)');
$criteria->params = array(':ids' => $ids); // binding array

$cmps = Component::model()
            ->with(array('type', 'values'))
            ->findAll($criteria);
```

Like this, I get "Array to string conversion" error.

When I used

```
$criteria->params = array(':ids' => implode(',', $ids));
```

I got nothing (empty array).

When I don't use binding, it works (but clearly not a good practice):

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addCondition('id_cty_cmp IN(' . implode(',', $ids) . ')');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Alright, here's the solution. May it help future googlers.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addInCondition('id_cty_cmp', $ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are wondering, the reason that

```
$criteria->params = array(':ids' => implode(',', $ids));
```

fails to return any records is because `:ids` will be bound with one string like this:

```
id_cty_cmp IN('1,2,3')
```

Clearly no `id_cty_cmp` matches the weird value `'1,2,3'`.

How you want it, which your solution provides, is:

```
id_cty_cmp IN('1','2','3')
```

Comment: yeah, I figured that out in the end. Still, why not give you a point ;)

Comment: Cheers @MightyPork.. Although technically you should mark your own answer as accepted and only upvote mine!

Comment: I kinda do want, being a developer my perfectionism demands correctness over points. Mega-appreciate the thought though :)

Comment: Alright, so be it. But it will let me pick my answer only after two days :(

Comment: Cheers! I forgot about that, but at least then it'll float yours to the top for the googlers.